# Table formatting with pandas Dataframe.to_latex()

Tags: python, pandas, latex

Is there any way to instruct pandas `Dataframe.to_latex()` to append `\footnotesize` (or other global options) for the output table in LateX? (Of course, other than manually append it, which is not efficient, as I'm generating lots of tables.)

So, right now my code produces the following LaTeX table:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{Caption of the table.}
\label{tab:06_01.example}
\begin{tabular}{lrrr}
\toprule
                    &            &  F-1 &    F-2 \\
Dataset & Model &            &       \\
\midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{\textit{H}} & Baseline &      0.904 & 0.887 \\
                    & Version2 &      0.939 & 0.927 \\
\cline{1-4}
\multirow{2}{*}{\textit{S}} & Baseline &      0.548 & 0.506 \\
                    & Version2 &      0.582 & 0.541 \\
\cline{1-4}
\midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{\textit{G}} & Baseline &      0.879 & 0.855 \\
                    & Version2 &      0.910 & 0.895 \\
\cline{1-4}
\multirow{2}{*}{\textit{T}} & Baseline &      0.911 & 0.877 \\
                    & Version2 &      0.940 & 0.913 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

from the following pandas dataframe:

```
                     F-1   F-2
dataset Model                 
H       Baseline   0.904 0.887
        Version2   0.939 0.927
S       Baseline   0.548 0.506
        Version2   0.582 0.541
G       Baseline   0.879 0.855
        Version2   0.910 0.895
T       Baseline   0.911 0.877
        Version2   0.940 0.913
```

and the corresponding dict for reproducibility purposes:

```
{'F-1': {('H', 'Baseline'): 0.9044961552465764, ('H', 'Fine-Tuned'): 0.9387767951280728, ('S', 'Baseline'): 0.547968262581014, ('S', 'Fine-Tuned'): 0.5815634664656218, ('G', 'Baseline'): 0.8793941208568047, ('G', 'Fine-Tuned'): 0.9102870296052078, ('T', 'Baseline'): 0.9110316123313993, ('T', 'Fine-Tuned'): 0.9404444309041384}, 'F-2': {('H', 'Baseline'): 0.8865304318012182, ('H', 'Fine-Tuned'): 0.9273671656403047, ('S', 'Baseline'): 0.5063582247873787, ('S', 'Fine-Tuned'): 0.5408162758046822, ('G', 'Baseline'): 0.8551648617281388, ('G', 'Fine-Tuned'): 0.8947135188980437, ('T', 'Baseline'): 0.8774834363467384, ('T', 'Fine-Tuned'): 0.9134634736945935}}
```

through an almost direct `dataframe.to_latex()`.
What I would like is to change some global table options, e.g. add \footnotesize, change \centering, like this:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\footnotesize %include or not
\centering %include or not
\caption{Caption of the table.}
\label{tab:06_01.example}
\begin{tabular}{lrrr}
\toprule
                    &            &  F-1 &    F-2 \\
Dataset & Model &            &       \\
\midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{\textit{H}} & Baseline &      0.904 & 0.887 \\
                    & Version2 &      0.939 & 0.927 \\
\cline{1-4}
\multirow{2}{*}{\textit{S}} & Baseline &      0.548 & 0.506 \\
                    & Version2 &      0.582 & 0.541 \\
\cline{1-4}
\multirow{2}{*}{\textit{G}} & Baseline &      0.879 & 0.855 \\
                    & Version2 &      0.910 & 0.895 \\
\cline{1-4}
\multirow{2}{*}{\textit{T}} & Baseline &      0.911 & 0.877 \\
                    & Version2 &      0.940 & 0.913 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

At 1st sight, it seems that there isn't such an option within [Dataframe.to_latex()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_latex.html), but I'm not sure about what *formatters* field can do. Furthermore, I don't know if Styler.to_latex() could help here.

**PS**: An additional nice-to-have would be to define after which datasets (e.g. S) to include a \midrule (as I would like to separate different types of datasets).

```
\begin{table}[H]
\footnotesize %include or not
\centering %include or not
\caption{Caption of the table.}
\label{tab:06_01.example}
\begin{tabular}{lrrr}
\toprule
                    &            &  F-1 &    F-2 \\
Dataset & Model &            &       \\
\midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{\textit{H}} & Baseline &      0.904 & 0.887 \\
                    & Version2 &      0.939 & 0.927 \\
\cline{1-4}
\multirow{2}{*}{\textit{S}} & Baseline &      0.548 & 0.506 \\
                    & Version2 &      0.582 & 0.541 \\
\cline{1-4}
\midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{\textit{G}} & Baseline &      0.879 & 0.855 \\
                    & Version2 &      0.910 & 0.895 \\
\cline{1-4}
\multirow{2}{*}{\textit{T}} & Baseline &      0.911 & 0.877 \\
                    & Version2 &      0.940 & 0.913 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: I think it's a good question too, but kindly add the code and the sample of the DataFrame that allow us to reproduce your current output.

Comment: @HarryPlotter: it's difficult because I am using a lot of code to generate the output from real data. But after having the dataframe, the code is simply dataframe.to_latex(escape=False,
                    sparsify=True,
                    multirow=True,
                    position='H')

Comment: I understand, I'm not asking for all of them. I was just asking for the sample of the DataFrame that you used to produce the latex string that you posted (first code block), so I can easily test it (and the code that you already provided).

Comment: @HarryPlotter: I edited the question, but tbh I'm not sure if this is what you pretend or not.

Comment: Yes it was, but please also include the output `df.to_dict()` or something similar, so we can easily reconstruct the DataFrame.

Comment: Now I understood! This is a very good way to reproduce results that I didn't know of. I just added the dict.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell latex to make these changes for all your tables:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

% change fontsize
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\footnotesize} 

% switch off centering in tables
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{\let\centering\relax}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{Caption of the table.}
\label{tab:06_01.example}
\begin{tabular}{lrrr}
\toprule
                    &            &  F-1 &    F-2 \\
Dataset & Model &            &       \\
\midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{\textit{H}} & Baseline &      0.904 & 0.887 \\
                    & Version2 &      0.939 & 0.927 \\
\cline{1-4}
\multirow{2}{*}{\textit{S}} & Baseline &      0.548 & 0.506 \\
                    & Version2 &      0.582 & 0.541 \\
\cline{1-4}
\midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{\textit{G}} & Baseline &      0.879 & 0.855 \\
                    & Version2 &      0.910 & 0.895 \\
\cline{1-4}
\multirow{2}{*}{\textit{T}} & Baseline &      0.911 & 0.877 \\
                    & Version2 &      0.940 & 0.913 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

test

\centering


test

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this will certainly fix these issues. But I was looking for  a python/pandas related solution, as it would give me more possibilities.